# How to create field named «from» in WTForms?

Tags: python, wtforms

I want to make a form for selecting an interval with two fields: `from` and `to`. But since `from` is a keyword in Python, I can't just write:

```python
class MyForm(Form):
    from = DateField()
    to = DateField()
```

This means that I have to name the field in Python differently but I still want to name the field in GET query exactly `from`. Is it possible with WTForms?

Comment: Does `from_ = DateField(label=u"from", id="from_")` work?

Comment: Why would `label` work? Label defines the human-readable field description, not the input's name.

Comment: There's `label`, but also `id`. The `id` may be what is translated into the input name inside the received query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's built in function `setattr`:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    to = DateField()

setattr(MyForm, 'from', DateField())
myform = MyForm()
```

You can access the field again with `getattr`:

```
from_ = getattr(myform, 'from')
```